# How to turn a system of partial differential equations into one equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a system of partial differential equations
  $$\partial_t g(x,t)=-(-a \partial^2_x f(x,t)+V(x)f(x,t)), $$
  $$\partial_t f(x,t)=(-a \partial^2_x g(x,t)+V(x)g(x,t)), $$
where $V(x)$ is known function and $a$ is a parameter.

I am wondering if there is a way to convert these equations into some equation for the ratio between the two functions $g(x,t)/f(x,t)$.

Comment: If that can help, using $z:= f-ig$, the equation can be written $iz_t=az_{xx}-Vz$. Then $g/f=-\cot\arg z$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem is that I obtained these equations exactly from the form which you wrote! :-) So it is funny that the easiest option is to come back to the original form which I am trying to avoid by any means.

Comment: Taking the logarithm of $z$ "extracts" the argument, but I don't see precisely how to exploit that. (But $z_t/z=\partial\log z/\partial t$.)

Comment: @QuantumNik Where did you got that equation from? Looks like Schrö, no?

Answer (score 0):

This PDE system is of first order in time. Often, such systems can be converted into a single PDE of higher order. To do so, let us differentiate the first equation with respect to $t$. Assuming the equality of mixed derivatives,
$$
\partial_{tt} g = a \partial_{xxt} f - V \partial_t f = (a \partial_{xx} - V)\,  \partial_t f \, .
$$
Using the second equation $\partial_t f = -(a\partial_{xx} - V)\, g$, the following PDE is obtained:
$$
\partial_{tt} g  = -a^2\partial_{xxxx}g + 2aV\partial_{xx} g - V^2 g \, .
$$
Similarly, one shows that $f$ satisfies the above PDE.